# Creating IP Table Rules for a Bluemix App in Secure Gateway - Obtaining App IP and App ID

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Regarding the section labeled "Creating IP table rules for a Bluemix app" @ https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/sg_023.html#sg_007 -- how can I obtain the "app_IP" and "app_ID" value for my Bluemix CloudFoundry app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into any issues with the API call itself, here is a previous post for [applying iptable rules specific to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547769/creating-ip-table-rules-for-a-bluemix-app-for-secure-gateway).

Here are the [CloudFoundry docs](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-INDEX) to show where you can get the IP of your app. (Here is another [reference to the docs hosted on Pivotal](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html).)